# MailApp AppScript: How to send an email to a thread using MailApp?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using [mailApp class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) of Appscript to send daily emails as shown below:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({to: emails[0],subject:subjectLine,htmlBody: htmlContent,cc: emails.slice(1,emails.length).join(",")});
```

What I observe is that for `subjectline = "TestEmail"` if sent more than once it gets sent to a new thread:

[image: Example Image]

What I actually want is to instead of MailApp creating a new thread, it must send it to the old thread if the subject line is the same. Like for example: `subjectline = "TestEmail"` then all the mails within this subject should fall under the same and not dispersed as shown above. And only when the subject line changes they should fall into a new email thread.

Has anyone faced the same problem? Does anyone know any work around for the same? Please let me know if you have a solution for the same.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Class MailApp**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)

- This service allows scripts to send email on a user's behalf. See also Gmail Service. Unlike Gmail Service, Mail Service's sole purpose is sending email; it cannot access a user's Gmail account.

---

**Workaround:**

You can prevent creating a new thread when sending emails using Gmail Service

[**Gmail Service**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail)

- This Service lets you send email, compose drafts, manage labels, mark messages and threads, and conduct a variety of other Gmail account management tasks.

---

**What you need to do:**

1. Search for a thread with a specific subject
2. Reply to that thread

---

**Sample Code:**

```
  var thread = GmailApp.search('in:anywhere subject:"Test_Email1" ')[0];
  Logger.log(thread);
  
  var invalidThread = GmailApp.search('in:anywhere subject:"Test_Email" ')[0];
  Logger.log(invalidThread);
  
  if (thread){
    thread.reply("This is a reply");
  }else{
    Logger.log("Subject not found in mail");
  }

  var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  Logger.log("Remaining email quota: " + emailQuotaRemaining);
```

> [GmailApp.search()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery)
> lets you search for specific queries in Gmail.
> This will return a [GmailThread[]](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread) type which is an array of Gmail threads matching this query

- In this sample code, I already created a Thread with **Subject:"Test_Email1"** and tried to access that thread using the [Gmail search operator](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) **"in:anywhere subject:"Test_Email1""**
- This search operator will search for threads with Test_Email1 subject anywhere in your Gmail, including spam and thrash folder.
- I also included a sample code where the subject "Test_Email" doesn't exist which will return an empty array.
- Once you have found your thread, you can use [GmailThread.reply()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#replybody) to reply in your current thread.

There are other reply options available in GmailThread. For more information, you can visit this link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread

By this, you may decide whether you need to create a new thread or reply with an existing thread in your Gmail.

---

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: wow thanks so much for your explanation and time!

Comment: You probably need `replyAll` here, cause `reply` replies to the sender (your GAS user email, not recipient) of the thread email. replyAll adds the recipient to cc then