# On Google Apps Script, is there a way to specify exactly what email address I'm sending a reply to when using the replyAll function?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am utilizing google apps to make a script that goes through my inbox and finds every thread with a particular label. Then for each thread, I want to send in a reply, but instead of just sending a reply to the recipient of the last message, I want to be able to send a reply to the recipient of the original message in the thread (i.e the person in the "to:" section of the first message).

The problem is that the reply and replyAll functions send a message, by default, to the person in the "to" field for the last message in the thread. I get that I'm able to access the recipient in the original message using something like this:

```
var firstMessage = thread.getMessages()[0].getTo();
```

and then input firstMessage as the "cc:" email in the reply, but then that looks weird in the Gmail app when the recipient of the original message isn't the last person to send a message in the thread.

Is there any way I could input in a "to:" field in my replyAll function the way I can put in a "cc:" field?

```
function sendFollowUpEmails() {
  var query = 'label:lasso-fu-08-19-2023';
  var threads = GmailApp.search(query, 0, 50);

  var followUpMessage = `Hello Fren :)

  How are you doing today?
  `;
  followUpMessage = followUpMessage.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var thread = threads[i];
    var firstMessage = thread.getMessages()[0]; // Getting the first message in the thread
    var toField = firstMessage.getTo();
    var ccField = firstMessage.getCc() || ''; // Including the original CC addresses
    var allRecipients = toField + (ccField ? ',' + ccField : ''); // Combining TO and CC into one list

    thread.replyAll('', {
      htmlBody: followUpMessage,
      replyTo: toField
    });
  }

  Logger.log("Follow-up emails successfully sent to " + threads.length + " threads");
}
```

I expected the code above to send a new reply to the recipient of the first message, but it just sends the reply to whatever the reply-to field is for the last sent message. And it's my understanding that all the "replyTo: toField" line does is set the 'reply-to' email for this new message to the value of toField.

I took a look at this [question] ([Sending a reply to a specific message in a Gmail thread using GmailApp in Google Apps Script and quoting the original message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76651480/sending-a-reply-to-a-specific-message-in-a-gmail-thread-using-gmailapp-in-google))on stackOverflow, but the fix was to use reply-to, and that doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: `But won't using sendEmail create a brand new thread instead of replying in the same thread?` Yes, apologies, that's correct.

Comment: Related question: [MailApp AppScript: How to send an email to a thread using MailApp?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65186524/1330560).

Comment: Instead of `MailApp.sendEmail()` (which doesn't maintain the thread), how about `reply(body, options)` [Doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#replybody,-options). Get the first message in the thread and reply; you still have all the options available.

Answer (score 0):

Though you are looping through threads, you don't need to *reply* to the thread (or use `thread.replyAll`).

You just need to send an email: `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)` [Doc Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options).

- recipient: `toField`
- subject: `firstMessage.getFirstMessageSubject()`
- body:  `followUpMessage`
- options: `{cc: ccField}`

Say, `MailApp.sendEmail(toField, firstMessage.getFirstMessageSubject(), followUpMessage, options);`

---

Regarding `replyTo` this is the default reply-to address (default: the user's email address)`. i.e., this would be *your* email address.

Comment: Thanks, fam. But won't using sendEmail create a brand new thread instead of replying in the same thread?

Comment: True. perhaps `reply(body, options)`; testing indicates that it uses the same thread.